# Sort Archive by Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I have a site with Taxonomy for State (Eg Victoria, Qeensland ETC) this taxonomy is called listing_state.

I also have a taxonomy called membership_type which can be Free or Paid.
These 2 taxconomies are for a CPT of listings

If I click on a taxonomy for State it brings the results as expected sorted by post date, how would I list the Paid Memberships before the Free memberships.

I am using Genesis and Lifestyle theme

Thanks
Richard

Comment: I have changed membership_type to a custom field (meta) instead of a custom taxonomy. How would I now arrange for the archive page to be sorted by meta. Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 1):

Other then two queries one for paid and on for free or creating a custom SQL query, its not possible natively.

> That’s not what taxonomies are for. Taxonomies are for grouping, not
>   for ordering by. If you want to order by something, it has to be
>   something in the post itself, not a term in a taxo. [Otto](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-1-advanced-taxonomy-queries/comment-page-1/#comment-6345)

So It would make more sense to set the Paid / Free as post meta and the sort by it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about this recently as well.  As quoted from Otto, taxonomies are meant to group posts, so I think the best way to do something similar to what you want is to create a custom walker that groups posts of the same term and displays them as such.